# Wordpress Plugin Update Failed Could not copy file error occurs

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I'm using amazon web server and while updating any plugin an "Update Failed: Could not copy file" error occurs.

I have set `/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs` and  `/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content` to 777, but still my plugins are not updating.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

```sh
sudo chown -R bitnami:daemon /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs
sudo find /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
sudo chmod 640 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-config.php
sudo find /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
```

After that, please restart services and try to update plugins again

```sh
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart
```